# In which context does $eval & $$eval execute in page/frame/elementHandle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

This is really getting to me. I am unable to access  global variable inside **$$eval()**, nor access other modules.

```
const util = require('util');
GlobalFlag=true;

.......

await page.$$eval(selector, (e) => { 
    console.log(e);
    GlobalFlag=false;
    console.log(util.inspect(e));
});
```

gives me **Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: util is not defined**

Comment: You won't be able to access `util` because it's Node package. It's likely unneeded. It's also unclear what purpose GlobalFlag serves in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$eval` evaluates the function in client-side context. It is stringified and called with `eval`. It doesn't have access to Node `GlobalFlag` because it doesn't exist in browser global scope.

`$eval` and `$$eval` [support additional arguments](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) that will be passed to evaluated function in case a variable should be read there. In order to write to a variable, the value should be returned from the function and assigned in Node context.

```
GlobalFlag = await page.$$eval(selector, (e) => { 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I get it now. So does that mean, i can't even do another **eval** - on **elementHandle** - inside **page.$$eval()** ?

Comment: Seems like that. This should be solved in another way, I guess.

Comment: It shouldn't work,as **elementHandle** is **puppeteer**. Shouldn't be available in browser. Can you fix your code, `util` won't be visible in **pageFunc**? will accept as answer.

Comment: Yes, sure, it won't be visible. Added browser-compatible alternative.

Comment: Is json available in browser?

Comment: Yes, it is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Browser_compatibility